# Unable to start the kernel of Jupiter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter

I'm quite new to Jupiter notebook.
So when I just try to create new python file, I get the following error.

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/libinzhou/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/Users/libinzhou/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/libinzhou/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "/Users/libinzhou/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "/Users/libinzhou/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/connect.py", line 13, in <module>
    from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir
  File "/Users/libinzhou/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "/Users/libinzhou/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 25, in <module>
    from IPython.core import release, crashhandler
  File "/Users/libinzhou/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/crashhandler.py", line 27, in <module>
    from IPython.core import ultratb
  File "/Users/libinzhou/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 115, in <module>
    from IPython.core import debugger
  File "/Users/libinzhou/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/debugger.py", line 47, in <module>
    from pdb import Pdb as OldPdb
  File "/Users/libinzhou/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pdb.py", line 76, in <module>
    import code
  File "/Users/libinzhou/code.py", line 9, in <module>
    yf=scipy.fftpack.fft(y)
  File "/Users/libinzhou/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/fftpack/basic.py", line 274, in fft
    n = tmp.shape[axis]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

It keeps going until it reaches 5. So I'm wondering what's going on? Is that about my python or Jupiter?

Comment: Is `yf=scipy.fftpack.fft(y)` code that you wrote? If so, please post the code around it.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize that part was related. It is another piece of code I tried to test. Deleting this file enables my Jupiter notebook to run correctly.